# Animate Back To Top Button

Tags: javascript, jquery, scroll

I have a back to top button that fades in at certain points on scroll. I am looking to change the script so instead of fading in and out that the button slides left 50px then slides right -50px; (off the screen)

Here is my code for fading in and out:

```
var offset = 220;
var duration = 500;

$(window).scroll(function() {
    if (jQuery(this).scrollTop() > offset) {
        $('.back-to-top').fadeIn(duration);
    } else {
        $('.back-to-top').fadeOut(duration);
    }
});

$('.back-to-top').click(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    $('html, body').animate({scrollTop: 0}, duration);
    return false;
})
```

I tried this but its not working for me:

```
var offset = 220;
var duration = 500;

$(window).scroll(function() {
    if (jQuery(this).scrollTop() > offset) {
        $('.back-to-top').animate({ "left": "+=50px" }, duration );
    } else {
        $('.back-to-top').animate({ "right": "+=50px" }, duration );
    }
});
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Where is your btn located? bottom-center, bottom-left or bottom-right?

Comment: Its a fixed position here is the CSS code - `.back-to-top {
 position: fixed;
 width: 42px;
 height: 42px;
 bottom: 20px;
 right: 50px;
 background: url(../img/back-to-top-btn.png) no-repeat;
 text-indent: -9999px;
 display: none;
}`

Answer (score 0):

How abt this one :-

```
var offset = 220;
var duration = 500;

$(window).scroll(function() {
    if (jQuery(this).scrollTop() > offset) {
        $('.back-to-top').animate({ "right": "+100px" }, duration );
    } else {
        $('.back-to-top').animate({ "left": "0px" }, duration );
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this...

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
    if (jQuery(this).scrollTop() > offset) {
      $('.back-to-top').animate({"left":"-50px"}, "slow").removeClass('visible');
 }  else {
      $('.back-to-top').animate({"left":"50px"}, "slow").addClass('visible');
 }
});
```

or you can use the jquery UI based example..like this

```
$('.back-to-top').hide('slide', {direction: 'left'}, 1000);
```